# Timeout error while running FFmpeg as a process in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, process, timeout, runtime-error

I'm trying to create a process for FFmpeg video compression at runtime. In my local system, it runs within 30 seconds. When I tried to run it in the server, it starts throwing a timeout error after 60 seconds. When I manually ran the command in the server, it took around 2 minutes. I came to know that some configuration in `php.ini` needs to be modified. I tried changing the configuration of the process to 300 seconds. Still, the same timeout error is being outputted.

```
The process "/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i '/var/temp/5e7de5a9de7c2/creme bulee-01-infuse
the cream and milk.mp4' -s 1668x2224 -c:a copy '/var/temp/5e7de5a9de7c2/compre
ssed/temp_creme bulee-01-infuse the cream and milk_1668x2224.mp4'" exceeded th
e timeout of 60 seconds.
```

In `php.ini`, I have the following configuration:

```
max_execution_time = 300 
max_input_time = 300
```

How do I stop my process from timing out?

Comment: Is it a command line script?

Comment: @Vishal yes, I'm creating a command as a process in runtime.

Comment: what is current location of php.ini? Is it a linux server which you are using?

Comment: yes its Linux distribution Ubuntu and path=/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini and

Comment: Edit this /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini file

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: Add set_time_limit(300) at the top of your script or ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' )  if first one doesn't works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210473/discussion-between-karthi-keyan-and-vishal).

Answer (score 2):

I was have same error, you need to add settings in FFMpeg::create and use FFMpeg::create

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create(
  array(
   'timeout' => 0, // The timeout for the underlying process
  )
);
$ffmpeg->open($video_path);
```

More info here https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Answer (score 0):

`max_execution_time` directive in php.ini does not affect shell commands as noted in the manual (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php for details)

My wild guess is that you are using `Symfony\Component\Process\Process` as by default it's timeout is exactly 60 seconds and your error message looks familiar. If I'm right, please [try increasing the timeout](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#process-timeout):

```php
$process = new Process($ffmpeg_cmdline);
$process->setTimeout(3600);
$process->run();
```